# OrmLite: Grouped Where Clauses with Joins

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using ORMLite within my Android Application which uses a Database to Create/Update/Delete Objects.
I have the following table structure:

**Table Wine**

- Country (own table / dao)
- Winery (own table / dao)
- Comment
- PurchasePlace
- some more columns, which are not relevant for this

**What i am doing (only the crucial part):**

In Words: 
I want to show all Wines, where certain fields match a user input, but respecting the wine-type, which relates to a constant.

Preparing the Join Query Builder:

```
queryBuilderWinery.where().like("name", "%Value%");
queryBuilderCountry.where().like("name", "%Value%");

queryBuilderWine
.join(queryBuilderWinery)
.join(queryBuilderCountry)
.where().like("name", "%Value%")
.or().like("purchasePlace", "%Value%").and().eq("wine_type_id", 1)
```

**Producing:**

```
FROM wine
INNER JOIN winery
   ON wine.winery_id = winery.id
INNER JOIN country
   ON wine.country_id = country.id
WHERE ((wine.name LIKE '%in%' OR wine.comment2 LIKE '%in%') AND wine.wine_type_id = 1)
OR (winery.winery_name LIKE '%in%')
OR (country.country_name LIKE '%in%')
```

**Where clause, which would be needed:**

```
WHERE (wine.comment like '%Value%' OR 
        wine.purchasePlace like '%Value%' OR 
        winery.name like '%Value%' OR 
        country.name like '%Value%') 
    AND wine.wine_type_id = 1

or 

WHERE  wine.wine_type_id = 1
    AND (wine.comment like '%Value%' OR 
        wine.purchasePlace like '%Value%' OR 
        winery.name like '%Value%' OR 
        country.name like '%Value%')
```

My question is, can this be done? I have read the documentation on this, i know a could use RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) or create the where clause with groups, but i am not sure on how to group the where 
clause correctly, since all joins will have an OR Clause as well, and i need the AND Clause grouped seperatly.
If i would use Where Grouping, would this have effect on the Join-Conditions as well?

Any help appreciated.

**Update:**
I tried a raw Where Clause, but same Problem here, i cannot imagine a way, where i can group the WhereClause over more than one Table...

```
WineDAO wineDAO = new DatabaseHelperProvider().get(this).getWineDAO();
CountryDAO countryDAO = new DatabaseHelperProvider().get(this).getCountryDAO();
WineryDAO wineryDAO = new DatabaseHelperProvider().get(this).getWineryDAO();

QueryBuilder<Wine, Long> wineQueryBuilder = wineDAO.queryBuilder();
wineQueryBuilder = wineQueryBuilder.join(countryDAO.queryBuilder()).join(wineryDAO.queryBuilder());

Where<Wine, Long> where = wineQueryBuilder.where().raw("(winery.name = ? OR country.name = ?) AND wine_type_id = ?",
        new SelectArg("winery.name", "in"),
        new SelectArg("country.name", "in"),
        new SelectArg("wine_type_id", 1));

String prepStatement = wineQueryBuilder.prepareStatementString();
List<Wine> query = where.query();
int i = query.size();
```

This will not work, because the column `winery.name` obviously is not contained within the table `wine`...

Comment: I crrently have the same problem as you have and the only solution I came up with so far to write the whole query as raw sql and use the `rawRowMapper` to get the object(s). Additionally I had to refresh the object afterwards because foreign fields where not loaded initially.

Comment: I would like to avoid parsing this as a raw query, because a built up a jpql like syntax / own objects which are query definitions upon the ormLite query builder. Keep me tuned if you see any other chance rather than a raw query. I personally do not have time at the moment to work on this. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've also tried a lot of different aproaches, but had no success.